# C# Tasks get result or catch exception

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I have:

```
public static async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
```

I would like to do this:

```
string rez1;
static void test()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
            //How can I get result like rez1= httpRequest((HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("google.com")));
            //or catch WebException here.
        });
    }
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. What is not working or where you have trouble doing?

Comment: in Action, which I post to StartNew() method I can't catch exception

Comment: I'm no expert.  But if `httpRequest` is `async` doesn't that mean you don't have launch the task yourself?  It will be done for you by the function?

Answer (score 3):

You have it mixed up a little bit. When your methods signature is:

```
public static async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
```

That means "this method is invoked asynchronously, i will call it and it will return imminently with a promise to finish in the future".

You should change your method to look like this:

**Edit**

Fixed the code according to the comments made.

```
public static Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
{
  return Task.Factory.Startnew(() = > {
      return HttpWebRequest.Create("google.com")
  }
}
```

When your method is marked as async, that means the caller might think it is "pure" async, which means no threads execute behind the scenes. If you do fire up a new thread (as you are doing here, by using a Thread Pool thread) you should explicitly comment your method and tell your invoker that he will be firing up a new thread.

You can save yourself firing up a new Task if you're using .NET 4.5 and have access to the new HttpClient class.

You can change your method to look like this:

```
public static async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
{
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com")
  var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  return stringResult;
}
```

Comment: You have made a common mistake in the above answer. You don't need to ``await`` in the body of your method. You can just return ``Task<string>`` result from ``ReadStringAsync`` and remove the ``async`` declaration from ``httpRequest``.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: *"You can just return `Task<string>` result from ReadStringAsync and remove the async declaration from `httpRequest`"* - that is wrong, the change you propose won't event compile. You have to return a `string` from `async Task<string>` method.

Comment: If it's not clear what I mean have a look at the updated code here. https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/10640228.

Comment: Actually you are right. Because I can't eliminate the first await on httpClient.GetAsync then I am forced to await the second task.